# React native Array Sort problem when 2 array are the same value

Tags: arrays, react-native, sorting

I have a problem when I using the array sort function

I have 2 state value are saving the same array value, (devName and devNameSort)

I want to sorting the one of the array and try to get the index on the original array.
However, when I sorting the array "devNameSort", the "devName" would be changed together.
Would any method to fix the problem

```
The Value of
dev  = \["08d5", "151e", "d467", "0655", "a853"\]
devName = \["W1", "W4", "W2", "W3", "W0"\]
devNameSort = \["W1", "W4", "W2", "W3", "W0"\]
```

```
 this.state = {
            dev: this.props.route.params.dev,
            devName: this.props.route.params.devName, 
            devNameSort: this.props.route.params.devNameSort,
  }



    componentDidMount() {
        const sd = this.state.dev
        const sdn = this.state.devName
        console.log(sd);
        console.log(sdn);
        setTimeout( ()=> {
            const sdbs = this.state.devSort;
            console.log(sdn);
            sdbs.sort().map( (bs,index) => {
                const sdIndex = sdn.indexOf(bs)
                console.log(bs,":",index, sdIndex)
                console.log(sd[sdIndex])

            })
        }, 1000);
}
```

| OutPut | Expect result |
| --- | --- |
| LOG ["W1", "W4", "W2", "W3", "W0"] | LOG ["W1", "W4", "W2", "W3", "W0"] |
| LOG W0 : 0 0 | LOG W0 : 0 4 |
| LOG 08d5 | LOG a853 |
| LOG W1 : 1 1 | LOG W1 : 1 0 |
| LOG 151e | LOG 08d5 |
| LOG W2 : 2 2 | LOG W2 : 2 2 |
| LOG d467 | LOG d467 |
| LOG W3 : 3 3 | LOG W3 : 3 3 |
| LOG 0655 | LOG 0655 |
| LOG W4 : 4 4 | LOG W4 : 4 1 |
| LOG a853 | LOG 151e |

--------- 14/12/2022 update ---------

I updated the code as const a copy, but it not work too

```
        const sdn = this.state.devName
        const sdCopy = this.state.devName
        console.log("Orginal - before sort", sdn);
        sdn.sort()
        console.log("Orginal", sdn);
        console.log("Copy", sdCopy);
```

```
 LOG  Orginal - before sort ["W4", "W1", "W3"]
 LOG  Orginal ["W1", "W3", "W4"]
 LOG  Copy ["W1", "3", "W4"]
```

I Find the solution, but don't understand why it work.

```
const sdn = this.state.devName 
const sdCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sdn))
sdCopy.sort().map((bs,index) => {
                const sdIndex = this.state.devName.indexOf(bs)
                console.log(bs,":",index, sdIndex)
                console.log(sd[sdIndex])
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

The same variable is passed as props.
Make a copy of one of the arrays before sorting.

`const sdn = [...this.state.devName]`

Answer (score 0):

In javascript arrays and objects are mutable. you have to create copies of them for immutable behavior. One way is by using spread operator.

```
const shallowCopy = [ ...originalArray ]
```

Comment: Hi. I have copy the value to a new array but it still not work, the details have been updated in the question

Comment: Try copying like this : 
 const sdCopy = [... this.state.devName]